# MKMapView heading features in Android with Google Maps APIs?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, mkmapview, android-sensors

How can I implement MKMapView heading features in Android with Google Maps APIs?

Screenshot: [iOS MKMapView with heading example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm3Wg.jpg)

I would use sensors to the orientation of the map and display the map as if you were a navigation mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [MapView](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) which is just one of the several [Map Objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map).

> A View which displays a map (with data obtained from the Google Maps
>   service). When focused, it will capture keypresses and touch gestures
>   to move the map.
>
> Users of this class must forward all the life cycle methods from the
>   Activity or Fragment containing this view to the corresponding ones in
>   this class.

For actual codes checkout the [Google maps android samples](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples) in Github.